# How to run a set of commands with a for loop inside a script with differen user (su -c)

Tags: bash

I need to run set of commands that consists of for loops in my script with specific user. I don't know how to o that without for variable expanding like for example here:

```
su -c "for var in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo '$var' done" someuser
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I thought about running a loop with many `su` calls but that seems pretty bad.

EDIT:
As someone noted in the comments `var` is not expanding but I get an error: `sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")`

Comment: Btw.: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have forgotten a semicolon, I would do it this way!

```
su -c 'for var in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $var; done' user
```